# Is it true that every uniformly continuous strictly convex function on convex compact subset of a finite-dim normed vector space has unique minimizer?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a convex compact subset of a finite-dimensional normed vector space and let $f:C \to \mathbb R$ be strictly convex and uniformly continuous function (e.g it is sufficient that $f$ be Lipschitz continuous).

> **Question.** Is it true that $f$ has exactly one minimizer ?

Comment: The set of minimizers of a convex function is convex, because it is a sublevel set. So you may assume wlog that your function is constant...

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First, since $f$ is continuous and $C$ compact, there is $x \in C$ with $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for all $y \in C$. Assume that $z \in C$ is a second minimizer with $x \not= z$. Then $f(x) = f(z)$ and since $f$ is strictly convex we get $f(u) < \frac{1}{2} f(x) + \frac{1}{2} f(z)$ for $u := \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} z \in C$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks (upvoted). Someone has voted the question be closed. Donno if I should be accepting this answer or closing the question. This place is weird at times...